# concat_ws and coalesce in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Pyspark, I want to combine concat_ws and coalesce whilst using the list method.  For example I know this works:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws, col

df = spark.createDataFrame([["A", "B"], ["C", None], [None, "D"]]).toDF("Type", "Segment")

#display(df)

df = df.withColumn("concat_ws2", concat_ws(':', coalesce('Type', lit("")), coalesce('Segment', lit(""))))
display(df)
```

[image]

But I want to be able to utilise the *[list] method so I don't have to list out all the columns within that bit of code, i.e. something like this instead:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws, col

df = spark.createDataFrame([["A", "B"], ["C", None], [None, "D"]]).toDF("Type", "Segment")

list = ["Type", "Segment"]

df = df.withColumn("almost_desired_output", concat_ws(':', *list))
display(df)
```

[image]

However as you can see, I want to be able to coalesce NULL with a blank, but not sure if that's possible using the *[list] method or do I really have to list out all the columns?

Comment: do you want to concat all the columns `*df.columns` ?

Comment: no, just the columns I put into the list, which I know is all columns in my example but that won't be the case in the actual scenario

Comment: The other day someone noticed that they didn't need "concat_ws" but just CONCAT instead.  Idk if this applies here, but worth a look.

Comment: yep! except I changed df.schema.names to list because I don't want to use all columns, but apart from that it was absolutely spot on!  Additionally your solution also ensured my other columns remain NULL, which is exactly what I want, so thank you!

Comment: I need to use concat_ws and not concat because that enables me to control my separator, and also concat cannot handle NULL because if even just one of the columns is NULL then the output will be NULL

Comment: Yes, you can use an intermediate list in case of a subset of columns. Glad it helped.

Comment: last question sorry, I don't actually need alias(name) do I?  Removing it seems to have done the same trick

Comment: `concat_ws` can handle nulls by itself -- it removes the nulls

Comment: @samkart it'll ignore the whole column in that case i.e. - A: vs A

Comment: @tommyhmt Yes since we're not appending/reusing those columns anyway, we can work with whatever name it generates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

Iterate over list of columns names

```
df=df.withColumn("almost_desired_output", concat_ws(':', *[coalesce(name, lit('')).alias(name) for name in df.schema.names]))
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Or, Use fill - it'll fill all the null values across all columns of Dataframe (but this changes in the actual column, which may can break some use-cases)

```
df.na.fill("").withColumn("almost_desired_output", concat_ws(':', *list)
```

Or, Use selectExpr (again this changes in the actual column, which may can break some use-cases)

```
list = ["Type", "Segment"] # or just use df.schema.names
list2 = ["coalesce(type,' ') as Type", "coalesce(Segment,' ') as Segment"]
df=df.selectExpr(list2).withColumn("almost_desired_output", concat_ws(':', *list))
```